# Subdomains, redirections and YSlow

Tags: subdomain, yslow, pagespeed

I've created a subdomain to host all my images (e.g. `http://images.domain.com`, which points to my `public_html/images/` folder). When I try to access a particular image via the browser, I am getting redirected. For example, I go to `http://images.domain.com/foobar.jpg`, I am redirected to `http://www.domain.com/images/foobar.jpg`.

Why would I get redirected? This is causing YSlow to lower my overall grade. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely is the web server that's serving the images domain (probably the only web server you have). Without info on the server you're using, it's impossible to tell you how to fix it, but it's definitely a configuration option in the server.

Comment: It was my .htaccess. I was forcing a "www" in the URL; somehow it was causing the redirection, I think.